# Summary.glm to CSV file?

Tags: r

I am struggling with printing results from "summary.glm" to a CSV file. My code, which is rather simple, is as follows:

```
results <-glm(dv ~ iv + iv2, family=binomial, data=dataframe)
results_df <-summary.glm(results)
write.csv(results_df, "myCSV.csv")
```

This yields the error: `cannot coerce class 'summary.glm' into a data.frame'`.

All that I really need to do is export my coefficients, as odds ratios, into a CSV file that also includes standard errors and p-values. I'm sure there is a package to do this; I just haven't found it. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
results_df <-summary.glm(results)$coefficients
```

This extracts the coefficients data frame.

Comment: How do I do the reverse process? That is get the Formula back from the CSV file?

Comment: @RamGAthreya: there is no way to do it from this kind of file: all that is being stored is the coefficients, not the formula.

Comment: Oh then is there no way to save formulae for future use? I would really like to do that since I don't want to relearn my model every time I want to make a prediction.

Comment: @RamGAthreya You can certainly save your formula for future use, just not in a `csv` file. The best way to save an R object is using `save(obj, filename="myfile.Rdata")`, then later `load("myfile.Rdata")`. See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/save.html)